# Building error when building Android Rom (ABC Rom - based on PureNexus, based on AOSP)

Tags: android, linux, build, ubuntu-14.04, building

I getting this build error when doing mka bacon after breakfast [device].

I have tried also using make clobber to clean it out so it's fresh however I still get this error. I have tried removing the line "#include " from LunaOS/external/busybox/scripts/basic/fixdep.c, however that still doesn't fix it.

The build log can be found here - http://pastebin.com/dNXfs91K

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm on Linux Mint 17.3, and people have confirmed that my environment is setup correctly - i.e. following the same tutorials, putting in the right commands to download build tools, etc.

Thanks in advance.